Child air ticket booked as an adult ticket
I have booked 2 adult tickets for myself and wife and 1 child ticket for my 5-year-old daughter via a 3rd-party travel agent site to travel later this year.
All the airlines (Thai, Oman, Egypt air and Philippine Airlines) in the booking show my 5-year-old as an adult.
I called the airlines and the travel agent and they said it’s not a problem.
Has anyone experienced this before? And were you able to check in smoothly?

It shouldn't be a problem. In recent past there were the contrary problem: adult considered children because of different usage of prefixes in India vs. UK/US, and just pilots noticed it (about performance/fuel consumption). -- But I would check carefully all data: it may be a hints of careless agent.

These days there really is any "child ticket". If you have a seat you pay the adult price. The only exceptions are infants under 2 that can go as "lap child" without their own seat.   Di you pay  different price for your child than you did for yourself?

@Hilmar While this may be true for many airlines and/or routes and/or fares (especially LCCs?), there are airlines which do sell differently priced tickets. Just checked AF on a CDG-HKG flight and 1 adult + 1 child is less than 2 adults (not a lot, about 20% of one adult fare). They actually have many different age brackets: infant (<2), child (2-11), youth (12-17), youth (18-24), student (18-29), adult and senior (65+). I haven't checked all cases to see the result.

Like @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't think it would be an issue, but you may have lost out on possible cheaper fares. Also remember that if they give any advice on required paperwork, they may not give the right ones. Children may need less or more documentation than adults, depending on the countries involved.

@jcaron: hence my question about whether there is a price difference. If the price is the same , the ticket is the same.

Some airlines just don't have a separate fare for children, so they will sell "adult ticket" for any age.

@jcaron: but that field would be in API (data for arrival country) so on a different form/page (and airlines usually never connect the two, I think for good reasons: passport for travel vs. for immigration/entry). In any case such info should be found as Date of Birth not just a field "Adult/Children/Infant".

This is not a problem.  Child tickets are a pricing concept on some airlines that give discounts, but when it comes to actually filling physical seats on a plane, there's only two options: adult (butt in seat) and infant (held in somebody's lap = no butt in seat).  So everybody who needs a seat, meaning is not an infant, will show up as "adult" in some systems.
